# Question on Running mod_perl + apache + Windows

Tags: perl, apache

I had developed web applications under environment mod_perl + Apache + Linux.

Now, I want to deploy a web application solution to my client, under Windows.

I was wondering any problem you guys encounter, when running mod_perl + Apache + Windows?

(1) Can I get Perl additional library (CPAN?), and being used in my web application easily? "Easily" means, no manual compilation. No complex configuration setup.

(2) How about Linux command feature? Perl integrate well with Linux utility to perform certain tasks. But if come to Windows, does it able to offer the similar features as in Linux's?

I am open to other web development environment under Windows (PHP or Python). The reason I choose Perl, as I know the language. I just do not want to switch to other language without a good reason.

Comment: Last I heard, Apache doesn't recommend running it on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not use mod_perl but for your question 1, you can take a look at the [installation docs.](http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/os/win32/install.html) . I have used Activestate Perl and PPM before and using ppm to install modules is easy.

for (2), Perl is a programming language and it comes with builtins and modules to do what *nix tools do, so there should be no problem. (there is no need to make calls to use *nix tools unless really necessary). Always check CPAN/PPM to see if there are modules to do what you want.

Personally, I prefer PHP if i am doing web programming because its easy to setup and lots of nice features already done specifically for web programming.